# Unable to access PostgreSQL running in Linux Ubuntu on top of Hyper-V in Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, hyper-v

I got this confusing error of unable to access PostgreSQL running inside a Linux on top of Hyper-V on Windows 10.

Below is part of my `hb_pga.conf`. I already check it using psql `show hba_file` that I edited the correct configuration file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

If I add `listen_addresses='*'`, I can't access it from within linux VM itself (nor Windows host). But If I remove `listen_addresses`, and test using IP connection via `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres postgres`, it will work.

I am using default switch and add another internal switch for samba mounted drive. Not sure whether that means something though.

Using this command to check all opened ports:

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1368/postgres`

Shouldn't 127.0.0 be 0.0.0.0 to allow connecting from outside?

Comment: in your vhost setup, ensure that you have added 2 the network adapters. 1 adapter for HOST to GUEST and another for GUEST to HOST

Comment: not sure how to do that. Is that Hyper-V switch manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Turn out, that `listen_address='*'` argument is on different file on the same directory with `pg_hba.conf`, that is `postgresql.conf`

Adding `listen_addresses='*'` to `postgresql.conf` solved this issue.

I put all of it here, should you need it https://medium.com/@swdev/quick-start-postgresql-on-linux-windows-and-hyper-v-bf5eef40eb84